# creating a cylinder like shape in opengl by copying lines

Tags: opengl

```
#include <glut.h>

void Draw() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-4.0);
glPointSize(9);
glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

glEnd();
glFlush();
}

void Initialize() {
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
//glViewport(0,0,9,9);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

gluPerspective(45.0, 1.00, 1.0, 10.0);
}

int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(250, 250);
glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
glutCreateWindow("cse 404");
Initialize();
glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

what i am trying is to create a cylinder like shape with gl_lines i.e copying lines one after another and rotate the whole thing in gluperspective.

```
GLUquadricObj *quadratic;
quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
gluCylinder(quadratic, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 ,25, 25);
```

this above code can give me cylinder but i don't want that, i want a cylinder like shape created by copying lines one after another using gl_lines which is needed for my further work.

Answer (score 0):

Using immediate mode, you can draw several circles in a stack.
Each circle can be drawn easily with a :

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for ( angleRad=0 to 2 )
        glVertex3f(radius*cos(angleRad),radius*sin(angleRad),stackLevel);
glEnd();
```